# Android Studio gcm repeat notification

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop this scenario in Android studio and was wondering if its possible.

User A presses a button in the app and broadcasts their location to a server. If User B/C/D is nearby, they receive a notification that User A is broadcasting until User A decides to stop. (Maybe an alarm?).

- Can I implement this with GCM? I have worked with it before.
- How can I constantly broadcast my location (like in uber) to the server when the app is open? Do I do a separate java class that has a thread or runnable?

Hope these questions can be answered.

Comment: yes you can send your location again and again through onlocationchanged method

Comment: How about getting users on the same app to see it? Is there a function in Android that I allows for that?

Comment: means getting the location of users near by you??

Comment: I mean if User A and User B have the same app. Both keep broadcasting their location to the server. How do I then make it so that the server shows maybe a pin of User A on User B's phone. Do I write a php script for that?

Comment: there are many apps on play store like this check this--> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsp.android.friendlocator&hl=en http://downloads.tomsguide.com/GPS-Friend-Finder,0301-43850.html       and some source code too check this--> http://www.kashipara.com/project/android/437/friend-tracker-android-project-source-code